# Iterate through the dataframe and skip when it meets specific values

Tags: python, data-science

I have data that looks like this:

[image: data]

Now I want to make a string that has a format like this:

Hello {first_name} {last_name}, this is the list of fruit that you want

1. {fruit_0} with {colour_0} colour
2. {fruit_1} with {colour_1} colour
3. {fruit_2} with {colour_2} colour

So the expected output would be (example first row):

```
Hello Maria White, this is the list of fruit that you want
1. apple with pink colour
```

But when I code it turns out:

```
Hello Maria White, this is the list of fruit that you want
1. apple with pink colour
2. - with - colour
3. - with - colour
```

This the code that I used:

```
import pandas as pd

  df = pd.read_excel("fruit.xlsx")
  for x in x.dfitertuples():
    first_name = x.first_name
    last_name = x.last_name
    fruit_0 = x.fruit_0
    fruit_1 = x.fruit_1
    fruit_2 = x.fruit_2
    colour_0 = x.colour_0
    colour_1 = x.colour_1
    colour_2 = x.colour_2
    
    message = f"""
  Hello {first_name} {last_name}, this is the list of fruit that you want
1. {fruit_0} with {colour_0} colour
2. {fruit_1} with {colour_1} colour
3. {fruit_2} with {colour_2} colour
"""
print(message)
```

Thank you

Comment: Format each line separately and only include it in your output if `fruit_*` is not `"-"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array to store the colours and fruits. This way you can iterate through all the colour/fruit pairs.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("fruit.xlsx")
for x in x.dfitertuples():
    first_name = x.first_name
    last_name = x.last_name
    fruits = [x.fruit_0,x.fruit_1,x.fruit_2]
    colours = [x.colour_0,x.colour_1,x.colour_2]

    print(f"Hello {first_name} {last_name}, this is the list of fruit that you want")
    for i in range(fruits):
        if fruits[i] and colours[i]:
            print(f"{i+1}. {fruits[i]} with {colours[i]} colour")
```